# Performance: single or multiple jar?

Tags: java, performance, jar

I have on simple question!  Is there any difference between use one single or multiple jar on performance?

Comment: In what environment? Are the jars local? Do they have to be downloaded (e.g., as with an applet)? The more effort you put into your question, the better the answers you'll receive.

Comment: Performance depends on how you code. Not for the jar and its count. May loading in to the JVM matters sometime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*.jar` files are just a lot of `*.class` files compressed into one. Kind of like if you archive a lot of compiled java classes into a `*.zip` file. There won't be any extra lag in using multiple `jar`s, except for maybe the extra time required for the java runtime to locate, open and read each separate `jar` file.

So using multiple jars or just one jar file won't greatly affect the runtime performance, but it may slow down the start up time. Especially for applets, where the jars need to be downloaded first.

Comment: Thanks IntermediateHacker! You answered perfectly to my simple question ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If your program use multiple jars, it will take more memory of jvm permgen. But it will do nothing with performance if the heap of jvm is large enough.